# Problem with adding textbox to each of the row of datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 1 windows form with 1 textbox where user will type ProductId, press enter key and based on that products will be added to gridview.

Now when the new row is added to gridview,I want to add textbox with each row but the problem is I can see a cell non editable and textbox is not getting generated.

Code :

```
private void txtProductId_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string pathName = txtFilePath.Text;
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtFilePath.Text);
            DataTable tbContainer = new DataTable();
            string strConn = string.Empty;
            string sheetName = fileName;

            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pathName);
            if (!file.Exists) { throw new Exception("Error, file doesn't exists!"); }
            string extension = file.Extension;

            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls":
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
                case ".xlsx":
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
                default:
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
            }
            string fieldSelector = "[ProductID], [ProductName], [MRP] ";
            string query = $"SELECT {fieldSelector} FROM [{sheetName}$A1:F15535] WHERE [ProductID] = {Convert.ToInt32(txtProductId.Text)}";
            using (OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cnnxls))
                {
                    oda.Fill(tbContainer);
                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn textboxColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    grdProductList.Columns.Add(textboxColumn);
                }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

### Update

[image]

In last column I want to allow user to add final amount in a textbox considering discount for each of the product.

Comment: There's nothing that adds a Row to your DataGridView, here. Also, I doubt you want to add a Column to the DGV each time you fetch some Rows, right? Can you add some more details on this procedure? Btw, still on this piece of code?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with tbContainer.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes but ultimately i want textbox inside datagridview for each row and that is what i have done.Am i missing something ?

Comment: @Jimi User can add some products with columns like [ProductID], [ProductName], [MRP].Now what i want to allow is that user can enter Final Mrp value for some products in case if user wants to give discounts on some products.That is why i want to give textbox with each product so that user can enter final price(considering discount) of the product

Comment: After you have collected the data from Excel, add a DataColumn to your DataTable (set the data type to decimal or string). When you set the BindingSource.DataSource, you'll have an extra, editable, Column which the user can interact with, setting whatever needs to be set there. When you export the data, remember to treat this new Column the way it deserves.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it should bind and display your results from your xls/xlsx sheet and also add a textbox column as requested.

```
private void txtProductId_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        var pathName = txtFilePath.Text;
        var sheetName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathName);
        var tbContainer = new DataTable();
        var bindingSource = new BindingSource();  //Initiate new binding source
        var fieldSelector = "[ProductID], [ProductName], [MRP]";
        var query = $"SELECT {fieldSelector} FROM [{sheetName}$A1:F15535] WHERE [ProductID] = {Convert.ToInt32(txtProductId.Text)}";

        if (!File.Exists(pathName)) throw new Exception("Error, file doesn't exists!");

        grdProductList.AllowUserToAddRows = false;  //Prevent user from adding new rows
        grdProductList.DataSource = bindingSource;  //Link the binding source to your dgview

        using (var cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(MsXlConnStr(pathName)))
            using (var oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cnnxls))
                oda.Fill(tbContainer);

        tbContainer.Columns.Add("Discount", typeof(Int32)); //<-- Editable discount column
        bindingSource.DataSource = tbContainer;  //Display collected results in dgView     

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private string MsXlConnStr(string pathName)
{
    return new FileInfo(pathName).Extension.ToLower().Contains(".xlsx") ? 
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'" : 
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
}
```

**Note:** I shortened and cleaned the code a bit but I recommend wrapping with a `try catch` block to capture any additional exceptions.

[image]

Comment: This is just adding a column(which is not editable) and not textbox.

Comment: Ok. I've removed the `add.column` and added to your datatable the following `tbContainer.Columns.Add("Discount", typeof(Int32));` which will add a new column of `Discount` to your data table and bind to your dgview. This IS editable (unless you have changed your dgview cells to not be editable somewhere). Screenshot results above, I've manually added 5 and 7.